# Why can't change resolution of Image?

Tags: android, android-camerax

This is my code start camera and use `Camerax`:

```
ImageCapture imageCapture;
ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis;
private void startCamera() {

        final ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Camera provider is now guaranteed to be available
                    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();

                    // Set up the view finder use case to display camera preview
                    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();

                    int DefaultPictureSizeWidth=1280;
                    int DefaultPictureSizeHeight=720;
                    
                    imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                               .setTargetResolution(new Size(DefaultPictureSizeWidth,DefaultPictureSizeHeight))
                                .build();                   


                    imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1), new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
                                @Override
                                public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
                                    image.close();
                                }
                            }
                    );

                    // Set up the capture use case to allow users to take photos
                    ImageCapture.Builder imageCaptureBulder = new ImageCapture.Builder();
                    imageCaptureBulder.setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY);                    
                    imageCapture=imageCaptureBulder.build();
                    // Choose the camera by requiring a lens facing

                    CameraSelector.Builder bulder = new CameraSelector.Builder();                    
                    bulder.requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK);                   
                    CameraSelector cameraSelector= bulder.build();

                    // Attach use cases to the camera with the same lifecycle owner
                     try{
                         cameraProvider.unbindAll();
                         mCamera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)MainActivity.this,cameraSelector,imageCapture,preview,imageAnalysis);
                         
                         preview.setSurfaceProvider(
                                 mPreviewView.getSurfaceProvider());                       
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                       // Log.d(TAG, "Use case binding failed")
                    }



                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    // Currently no exceptions thrown. cameraProviderFuture.get()
                    // shouldn't block since the listener is being called, so no need to
                    // handle InterruptedException.
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }
```

I had setting `setTargetResolution` to `Size(1280,720)`

But Resolution of Result Image still is Maximum(4032x3024)

How can change resolution of Image?

Comment: I don't know too much about `CameraX`, but I think you need to set the resolution for the `Preview` as well, in the `bindToLifecycle` set the `imageAnalysis`  and `PreviewConfig` here's an example : https://github.com/LittleGentleman/DouyinDemo/blob/20eed12d4f32facb5035d1dd5dd60a4b77b35d89/app/src/main/java/com/gmm/www/douyin/utils/CameraHelper.java

Comment: Thank you, I had try set to Preview, but it still not working:   Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
                            .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280,720))
                            .build();

Comment: I'm not the owner of this project, but you can have a look : https://github.com/LittleGentleman/DouyinDemo/blob/20eed12d4f32facb5035d1dd5dd60a4b77b35d89/app/src/main/java/com/gmm/www/douyin/utils/CameraHelper.java

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/configuration):

> CameraX will ***apply the best suitable resolution based on the requests.***
> **If the primary need is to satisfy aspect ratio, specify only
> `setTargetAspectRatio`**, and CameraX will determine a specific resolution
> suitable based on the device. **If the primary need of the app is to
> specify a resolution in order to make image processing more efficient
> (for example a small or mid-sized image based on device processing
> capability), use `setTargetResolution(Size resolution)`**.

You could try

```java
imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        .setTargetResolution(new Size(DefaultPictureSizeWidth,DefaultPictureSizeHeight))
                                .build();                   
    .setTargetAspectRatio(Rational(3,4)) //Tweak this as desired
```

However, it generally appears that the target resolution is dependent on the device.